# Regex pattern doesn't print multiple line post a word match in a text file

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to print all the lines post a word match using re module in python 3.6. But it only prints a single line.

```
import re

filepath = "C:\\Users\srika\PycharmProjects\webDev\Py_AWS\error.txt"
with open(filepath, 'r') as fp:
    data = fp.read()
regexobj = re.compile(r'traceback (.*)', re.I)
output = regexobj.findall(data)
print(output)
```

Comment: you need to use dotall flag

Comment: `regexobj = re.compile(r'(?s)traceback (.*)', re.I);regexobj.search(data).group(1)`

Comment: regexobj = re.compile(r'(?s)traceback (.*)', re.I)
output = regexobj.search(data).group()    -----------------thanks, a little modification and it fixed my issue.